# $("#input").val() returning undefined while using $.post()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I feel silly not being able to solve this, but I keep having my post request coming up as undefined on the line $('#input').val().  Can someone help me solve this issue?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      let sr = $("#input").val();
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
          $.post("http://localhost:8080/", {subreddit: sr}, function(data, status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='content' style="height:100%, width:100%">
        <input id='input' type="text" placeholder='enter subreddit'/>
        <button>Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because that part of your script is running before your DOM is loaded. Move it inside your `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let sr = $("#input").val();
    //Rest of your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `let sr = $("#input").val();` part of your script should run when you click the button.

Move it inside the click handler like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function(){
    let sr = $("#input").val();
    $.post("http://localhost:8080/", {subreddit: sr}, function(data, status){
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I moved it inside the click handler, but it's still returning undefined.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was actually with the backend.  It kept returning undefined because I didn't call the .toString() method.  Thanks for the help guys.